# Server connectivity error while shifting site to a new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, hosting, google-search-console

I had my **wordpress** site on my sub domain blog.areobots.com. **I shifted my data from sub domain to my main domain (www.areobots.com) directory in file manager of hosting server. Both directories are pointing to the same mysql database.** In the **.htaccess** file of sub domain directory, I redirected all its links to my new domain. It been 2 months since I shifted it. Now two days ago I removed my files from sub domain directory except **.htaccess** file(this is to keep redirection). My main domain is working fine when open in the browser.

Now **Google web master tools** showing server connectivity error like shown in the image. Where as I also shifted my domain to new one in web master tools.
[image]

I have removed files from sub domain directory, because while applying for adsense ads on my main domain, they disapproved my adsense request because they said that you site is down/unavailable. I thought this might be the problem that both directories are having files. **Have I done right here?**

I have not worked in servers and not having any idea about DNS etc.

I will be very thankful if any body help me in that.

See my .htaccess file with the given link

[.htaccess file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8qiHDiC8qnbblNzS2hBQmtOUmM/view?pref=2&pli=1)

Comment: Could you paste your `.htaccess` file? You might have an antibot system preventing google from fetching your website.

Comment: You can use this tool to have more information: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch

Comment: Well, I have opened this tool, and it asked me verify property. I verified it and opened that property. It is again showing those error while crawling. What it has done? and what to do now?

Comment: Could you please post your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre , I have added a link to my htaccess file.